# Merge Tags - Chevy and Chevrolet

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Trying to update tags and see there are two tags: [chevrolet](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chevrolet) and [chevy](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chevy). There are a ton of questions in each, but would suggest merging [chevy](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chevy) into [chevrolet](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chevrolet) since [chevy](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chevy) is a nickname for the brand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done [chevy](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chevy) now maps to [chevrolet](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chevrolet)